# How to convert string of ASCII codes to string of characters?

Tags: javascript, string, ascii

Need to convert a string of ASCII code into the corresponding string of characters. String.fromCharCode() works only if I directly type in the ASCII codes but I need to use a variable name for this.

`code = codeArr.join('.');`
// 104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100

`String.fromCharCode(104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100);`
// hello world

`String.fromCharCode(code);`
// this returns blank? No errors just blank

Comment: `code` is a string of numbers concatenated with a dot. How is `String.fromCharCode()` supposed to work with this string when it expects `1..n` numbers?

Comment: Typo. I meant  code = codeArr.join(',');

Comment: Doesn't make it any better ;) `String.fromCharCode()` expects numbers not a string.

Comment: fromCharCode works with UTF-16 code units. If it is understood that you have ASCII code units or ISO 8859-1 code units, a code comment explaining why you can use fromCharCode is in order. Otherwise if you have code units from another character encoding, you can't use fromCharCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
let code = [104,101,108,108,111,32,119,111,114,108,100];

console.log(String.fromCharCode(...code));
```

Comment: That worked and saved me a step to since I didn't have to convert the array of codes to a string. Thanks for the answer and link!

Comment: @JeffS _"since I didn't have to convert the array of codes to a string"_ - Which was wrong in the first place.